SSRS reports requiring credentials every time
I set up a new SSRS2022 server. Everything works fine, we can access and etc, but every time we need to keep adding our credentials.
In the .config file I could find these rows:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/configure-windows-authentication-on-the-report-server?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN
Following Microsoft pages and StackOverflow answers couldn't fix this issue.
The old server has this different:
<RSWindowsBasic>
                <LogonMethod>3</LogonMethod>
                <Realm></Realm>
                <DefaultDomain>OUR.DOMAIN.COM</DefaultDomain>
            </RSWindowsBasic>

but adding that didn't help (actually adding that broke SSRS and I couldn't even start, so I removed)
Execution account is set to the domain service account that is the same as the service account.
